# Error importing 'CoreData/CoreData.h'

Tags: xcode, core-data, frameworks, import, linker-errors

I just finished my first successful CoreData store and fetch which worked fine in the simulator, but wouldn't run on my device (I got dozens of errors). Most of the errors were link errors and I was able to fix them by deleting all the links to the CoreData framework and then re-linking it in the build phases tab. This solved most of the errors when building for my device, but introduced 2 errors when building for the simulator. The errors are all the same thing "CoreData/CoreData.h file not found" although I checked the file directory and it seems to be fine. I also have another app from a tutorial that uses CoreData and it runs fine and has the same file directory. Specifically, the errors are in my NSManagedObject classes, fresh out of the .xcdatamodel and obviously occur on the line where I import .

Comment: I hours of troubleshooting, I was able to solve the issue by deleting the "Developer-old" folder.